# how to execute .deb files?

Tags: 13.04

I am new to Ubuntu, I am working on AVR micro controller for that I need to use AVARICE software, by using synaptic package manager I installed AVARICE but I am not able to find it in application files.

so how to open that software? and if any knows about AVARICE I request to help me in working over it

Comment: You said you already installed it, but you ask how to execute a .deb file, which is kind of a "installer" file. Did you already use the .deb file in some way? A double click on it should normally offer you to install the software. Did you do that but do just not find the application or do you really need help regarding the .deb file?

Answer (score 6):

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to "execute" a already installed package. In case of AVARICE, try to execute `avarice` in a terminal.